# Apache Shiro: GET /login results in 406 HTTP Response

Tags: jersey, jetty, dropwizard, shiro, jetty-9

I am running and app that uses Dropwizard 1.0.5 (Jetty 9.3.14) and Apache Shiro 1.2.6. Recently, I started getting "406 Not Acceptable" responses to GET requests for /login. A sample stacktrace is shown below.

The problem went away after restarting the app. Anyone have any ideas what the cause could be, or how I go about troubleshooting it?

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException: HTTP 406 Not Acceptable
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.getMethodRouter(MethodSelectingRouter.java:529)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.access$000(MethodSelectingRouter.java:94)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter$4.apply(MethodSelectingRouter.java:779)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.apply(MethodSelectingRouter.java:371)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:364)
at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:43)
at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at com.example.shiro.dropwizard.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240)
at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Probably not relevant to the problem, but for completeness, the app is running behind a Nginx reverse proxy.

The shiro.ini:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login
authc.successUrl  = /admin
logout.redirectUrl = /login

authc = com.example.shiro.CustomFormAuthenticationFilter

# tells Shiro to use form-based authentication
/login = authc
/logout = logout

# Form auth for everything
/** = authc
```

The class CustomFormAuthenticationFilter just extends FormAuthenticationFilter and has the method:

```
// Ensures this filter only swallows form data if the referrer is the login form.
    protected boolean isLoginSubmission(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
        {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            if (httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(POST_METHOD))
            {
                String referrer = httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER);
                if (referrer != null && !referrer.isEmpty())
                {
                    if (referrer.endsWith("/login"))
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What version of Shiro are you using? How have you configured it (shiro.ini)? How are you mapping /login to a resource (servlet, jersey resource, etc)

Comment: Shiro 1.2.6; more details added above that could be helpful.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this? Do you only see this when running in a development environment (e.g. `mvn jetty:run`).  If you can create a reproduce case and point us to the link, that would be great!

Comment: Unfortunately, its am intermittent error and I have yet to figure out how to reproduce it. Which of course, is one of the worst kinds of bug to troubleshoot...